# Spring MVC Controller method is not getting invoked on successful login from Spring Security - Getting 404 status

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring MVC with Spring Security. I have custom login page for authentication. After successful authentication of user, I want a controller method to be invoked named home() in WelcomeController.java

Below are my web.xml, test-serlet.xml, test-security-config.xml, pom.xml, WelcomeController.java and log files.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/test-security-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/test-security-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--Spring security filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

test-servlet.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

test-security-config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/welcome/denied">

        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN','ROLE_OEMMANAGER','ROLE_OEMSALESPERSON')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" method="GET"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/welcome/home" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>

    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="shuchi" authorities="ROLE_SUPERADMIN" password="a" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

WelcomeController.java

```
package com.test.web;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class WelcomeController {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WelcomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        log.info("--- home() Starts ---");
        System.out.println("--- home() Starts ---");
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = "";
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
        log.info("username=" + username);
        model.addAttribute("message",
                "Hi Tehre! You've reached the welcome page!");
        // ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDeniedPage() {
        // log.info("User's role is: "+ <sec:authentication
        // property="principal.authorities"/>);
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = "";
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
        log.info("username=" + username);
        log.debug("Received request to show denied page");

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/deniedpage.jsp
        return "denied";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

test.log

...

```
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/login.jsp'; against '/login*'
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login.jsp; Attributes: [isAnonymous()]
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9056f12c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5875e564, returned: 1
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:215 - Authorization successful
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:227 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
    2015-05-04 12:21:27 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /login.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
    2015-05-04 12:21:28 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
    2015-05-04 12:21:28 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:304 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
    2015-05-04 12:21:28 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:152 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:91 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@15ce9113. A new one will be created.
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:205 - Request is to process authentication
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG ProviderManager:152 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy:81 - Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy@cc026e6
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG SessionFixationProtectionStrategy:87 - Invalidating session with Id 'C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883' and migrating attributes.
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG SessionFixationProtectionStrategy:97 - Started new session: 4F86F4424F09507605F075E2A8F90748
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:319 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6124f8c9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca2d8be4: Username: shuchi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler:107 - Using default Url: /welcome/home
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to '/test/welcome/home'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:327 - SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@6124f8c9: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6124f8c9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca2d8be4: Username: shuchi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:171 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@6124f8c9: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6124f8c9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca2d8be4: Username: shuchi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6124f8c9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca2d8be4: Username: shuchi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /welcome/home at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/welcome/home'; against '/welcome/*'
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /welcome/home; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN','ROLE_OEMMANAGER','ROLE_OEMSALESPERSON')]
    2015-05-04 12:21:32 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@6124f8c9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@ca2d8be4: Username: shuchi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: C51942A05166FA866F8863CA07809883; Granted Authorities: ROLE_SUPERADMIN
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5875e564, returned: 1
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:215 - Authorization successful
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:227 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:323 - /welcome/home reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
    2015-05-04 12:21:33 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I really appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!

Comment: It's `default-target-url="/test/welcome/home"` instead of `default-target-url="/welcome/home"` similar to `access-denied-page="/test/welcome/denied"`

Comment: @Evgeni - thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but it results into login success getting redirected to http://localhost:8080/test/test/welcome/home instead of http://localhost:8080/test/welcome/home.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the controller request mapping with the root context, your controller should be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class WelcomeController {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WelcomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        ...     
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDeniedPage() {
        ...
    }
}
```

While in security config, change the access denied page to `"/welcome/denied"`:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/welcome/denied">

        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN','ROLE_OEMMANAGER','ROLE_OEMSALESPERSON')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" method="GET"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/welcome/home" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>

</http>
```

Comment: @Patrik LC, thanks. I get your point. I have made the changes in my controller to map to /welcome instead of /test/welcome. And also changed te denied page as you have suggested. However, the problem is not solved with that.